# How to define a list of macros in Cmake

Tags: c, cmake, macros

I'm trying to define a list of macros in Cmake.

Below code is in `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set(COMP_PN_LIST ${PN_LIST})
```

Below code is in `pn.cmake` file:

```
set(PN_LIST PN="100-X-Z12345RevB")
```

This generates the following errors:
`error: use of undeclared identifier 'X'`

```
#define PN 100-X-Z12345RevB
               ^
```

`error: use of undeclared identifier 'Z12345RevB'`

```
#define PN 100-X-Z12345RevB
                 ^
```

I'm trying with one-element list for now. I might need a list that will contain multiple elements.

Any advice is appreciated! I'm new to Cmake so still navigating for now.

I have tried `set(PN_LIST (PN="100-X-Z12345RevB"))` in `pn.cmake` file but I encounter `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

I should expect `#define PN 100-X-Z12345RevB` without errors

Comment: No, setting variables in CMake does not automatically result in `#define` statements. Show your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Sorry but codebase is proprietary, but the overall idea is included in the question above. Additional information while debugging, when I directly assign the string as `const uint8 PN_ARR[] __attribute__((section(".pn_cs"))) = "100-X-Z12345RevB";`, I have no problem. I'm having issue when I use the folllowing code: `const uint8 PN_ARR[] __attribute__((section(".pn_cs"))) = PN;`. Could it be just some syntax thing I am missing?

Comment: Yes, you are missing a [mre] that contains code that actually puts those macros in C code.

Comment: If you use `configure_file` and [`#cmakedefine FOO_STRING "@FOO_STRING@"`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.25/command/configure_file.html), for example, it is not even possible to encounter your issue.